# Jquery remove some symbol using replace

Tags: jquery

For an example , `$okay$` how to replace into `okay` ? I tried `replace("/$","");` and get `okay$` , how to remove both `$` symbol ? Any suggestion ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a regexp with `g` modifer, and note to escape the `$` with `\$`:

```
var str = "$okay$";
str = str.replace(/\$/g,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:-

```
var yourCase= '$okay$';
var result= yourCase.replace(/\$/g, '');
```

Demo:-
http://jsfiddle.net/Rj9bR/38/